# Error when writing "£" in a paragraph

Tags: html, symbols, sign, pound

I'm trying to put in a simple paragraph in which there are "£" signs denoting prices.

However, when the text appears on the webpage every "£" sign is preceded by a "Â" symbol.

Can anyone advise as to why this happens?

Any suggestions on how to stop this happening? See below snippets of the affects code.

```
<div id="dog_walks_text">
            <h4>Dog Walking Prices:</h4>
            <br>
            <p>GROUP WALKS
            <br>
            30 min - £6.50, plus £4 per additional dog from same household
            <br>
            60 min - £12.00, plus £6 per additional dog from same household
            <br>
            <br>
            ONE-TO-ONE WALKS
            <br>
            30 min - £9.00, plus £4 per additional dog from same household
            <br>
            60 min - £14.00, plus £6 per additional dog from same household</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: It happens because you are messing up the character encoding somewhere, or are not using the right one. So please go read up on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Adding meta tag in the head:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: @TomJardine-Smith UTF-8 is a character encoding capable of encoding all type of characters,  html by default uses ASCII which doesn't have all charcters encoded, with the meta charset you specify the HTML to use UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Ensure this is in the `<head>` of **every page**

Answer (score 0):

This can often happen is the font you're using is not on the local machine.

Firstly, make sure you're using a websafe font.

Secondly, trying inputting your "£" symbols as html code:

```
&#163;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. You're right, I'm not using a websafe font - but I am using fonts provided by Google Fonts and linking to them in the head tag - should that not be enough? Either way, the html version of "£" has done the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, as long as your google font is being referenced correctly, it should be fine. In that case, it is possibly the case that the google font you're using doesn't have a "£" symbol on it included in it although that does seems relatively unlikely. You'll be able to check if that is the case by going onto your google font and in the preview text box, typing in the £ symbol.

Comment: This wouldn't be very practical if all of your text has been using the simple £ key on a keyboard, as it could easily be fixed by setting the encoding meta tag, which should always be in every page.